# I am building an mp3 player using Arduino but the shield am using is the spark fun mp3 shield but its limited to 9 songs help me out guys

Tags: c++

***-Spark fun mp3 shield plus Arduino Uno I have written all code very well but  and its playing already but only 9 songs play I wanted to use the 1 shield but does not contain an SD card reader***

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: no the problem is not the code but they say its the shield that accommodates 9 songs

Comment: If its not a programming problem then this is the wrong site